# WSARecvFrom blocking

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, winsock2

For some reason when I call WSARecvFrom the function does not return until something is received.

```
_socket = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP, NULL, NULL, WS_OVERLAPPED);
...
sockaddr_in addr = ...
if(bind(_socket, (const sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != EXIT_SUCCESS) { ... }
...
HANDLE _handle = CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)_socket, _ioHandle, NULL, NULL);
...
_recvOverlap->OVERLAP.hEvent = WSACreateEvent();
DWORD sz = 0, flag = 0;
return WSARecvFrom(_socket, _recvBuf, 1, &sz, &flag, (sockaddr*)_recvAddr, &_recvAddrSz, (LPWSAOVERLAPPED)_recvOverlap, NULL);
```

Comment: You should revert your edit back to the original text and then post the solution as an answer instead. By editing the original question, you changed its meaning for future readers.

Comment: I would love to but I don't have 10 rep points... which is lame.

Comment: OK, then I posted one for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `WS_OVERLAPPED` (which as a value of 0) to `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` (which has a value of 1) instead.  You are not creating an overlapped socket correctly, so `_recvOverlap` is being ignored by `WSARecvFrom()`.

Comment: Voted up for you and because this is correct. Sorry for my incorrect (deleted) answer. I misread the post because I was on mobile.

Comment: @Impulse: You have now reached 15 rep, so you should be able to vote things up now.

Comment: I noticed. Voted it up.